# When a row selected, tableView didSelectRowAt not called in SearchTextField

Tags: swift, uitableview, combobox, dropdown, didselectrowatindexpath

In my IOS swift project  I use [SearchTextField](https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField)
,for a searcheable dropdown combobox. 
A few days ago my code was fine.But suddenly I realized that my searchTextField not working as it should be.

When I start to type more then 3 characters, it starts to displays results came from webservice, as expected.
But when I select a cell from tableView, nothings happen.
I discovered that when I select an item from list(tableView) code does not enter below method in SearchTextField.swift

```
 public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if itemSelectionHandler == nil {
            self.text = filteredResults[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].title
        } else {
            let index = indexPath.row
            itemSelectionHandler!(filteredResults, index)
        }
        clearResults()
    }
```

And also does not enter  "itemSelectionHandler" in my viewcontroller.swift but enters "userStoppedTypingHandler"

```
    @IBOutlet weak var mySearchTextField: SearchTextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        mySearchTextField.userStoppedTypingHandler = {
            if let criteria = self.mySearchTextField.text {
                if criteria.count > 3 {
                   ......
                   print("enters here")
                }
            }
        }

         mySearchTextField.itemSelectionHandler = { filteredResults, itemPosition in
          print("not enters here, cell selected")
       .....
       .....
        }
}
```

But code enters this method and shows the result in SearchTextField.swift,

```
        public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
print("cell ok")  
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: SearchTextField.cellIdentifier)    
            if cell == nil {
                cell = UITableViewCell(style: .subtitle, reuseIdentifier: SearchTextField.cellIdentifier)
            }
    ......
    ......
    return cell
    }
```

TableView datasource and delegate is ok.
There is no gestureRecognizer in my viewcontroller.
I opened an empty new project and only added SearchTextField pod and a uitextfield, it works fine.
I think something in my project or storyboard effects didselectat method.
What causes this problem?
Any idea?

Comment: You need to make sure your search table view is retained in memory as an instance variable of the view controller.

Comment: Assuming the search field in which you're typing is in a cell of another table view like the example in the library's README.md, and assuming the problem you describe is with the table view that shows the list of possible matches as you type, are you certain the delegate for _that one_ is set properly?

Comment: @Jim mysearchfield is a UITextField using SearchTextField.swift. I created new viewControIler and did not work, but I  created an empty new project and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my question.
Here is the solution:
I am also using IQKeyboard pod.
In my AppDelegate.swift file there are 3 line IQKeyboard code.
And when I comment out shouldResignOnTouchOutside line , my  didselectRowAt function called.
Because IQKeyboard's  shouldResignOnTouchOutside uses UITapGestureRecognizer

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    registerForPushNotifications()
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enable = true
    IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
    //IQKeyboardManager.shared.shouldResignOnTouchOutside = true
    return true
}
```